# Is there a Code Style option to have Visual Studio not reformat #pragma directives?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coding-style

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio how to style pragmas (e.g., `#define`, `#if`, `#else`, `#endif`, `#region`, et cetera)?

Normally, pragmas sit at the first character in a line. If I wanted them to appear inline and not have Visual Studio restyle them for me, how would I do that? I do not see anything in Tools | Options | C# | Code Style.

```
namespace MySolution.MyProject
{
    internal class MyClass
    {
        public void MyMethod1()
        {
            #if (USETHIS1)
                // code here
            #else
                // code here
            #endif
        }
    }
}
```

I did a search here on Stack Overflow and in Google, but did not see anything, maybe just how I searched. The compiler accepts the location anywhere.

As far as standards go, I prefer to see my pragmas inline, like above. How could I do that?

Comment: A minor correction: Unlike [`#if`, `#else`, and `#endif`], `#region` does not go to the beginning of the line by default.

Comment: Note: I spent the last 10 minutes looking, there isn't an option even in the latest version of 2019

Comment: Resharper has this ability i think